# NodeJS/Express: Concurrency issue when accessing res.locals

Tags: node.js, express

I have a web application based on NodeJS, Express and Jade 4.13.4. In `index.js` I have set up a route as follows:

**index.js**

```js
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , companyroutes = require('./routes/company')
(...)
app.use('/company/', companyroutes)
```

**routes/company.js**

```js
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()

router.all('/:id*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.companyUri = '/company/' + req.params.id;

  async.parallel([
    // company data
    function(done){
      api.getCompany(req.params.id, req.user, done)
    },
    // user follows data
    function(done){
      api.follows(req.params.id, req.user, 'company', done))
    }
  ],
  function(err, result){
    if (err){
      return next(err)
    }

    res.locals.company = result[0]
    res.locals.userFollows = result[1]

    company.getCompanyOverview(res.locals.company, function(err, results){
      if (err) {
        return next(err)
      }
      debug('render company overview')
      res.render('company-overview', results)
    })

  })

});

module.exports = router;
```

As you can see, I have a single route which is used as a middleware doing the following:

- enrich `res.locals` with some general company data (`company` and `userFollows` received from two asynchronous, parallel calls to an API)
- makes another call to `company.getCompanyOverview` which wraps a few more calls to the API using `async.parallel`. The received data is stored in `results`.
- render the Jade view `company-overview` using `results`.

So far so good. When making a single call to `http://localhost:3000/company/companyA` fetches all the data from the API and displays the data for `companyA` correctly by rendering the template.

However, with concurrent requests, the behavior is different. I use ApacheBench under OSX to put some load on the server by requesting a different company:

```
brew install parallel
echo /company/companyB | parallel 'ab -c 10 -n 5000 http://localhost:3000{}'
```

When accessing the site `http://localhost:3000/company/companyA` with a browser, the base data for `companyB` is shown instead of `companyA`.

The [Express Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) clearly say that `res.locals` is scoped to the lifecycle of a single request:

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the
>   request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during
>   that request / response cycle (if any).

To me however it looks like `res.locals` is being overwritten by the requests from ApacheBench. This is also the case when running AB from another machine!

I have already invested far too much time in this and I still don't get it. Is it a bug in Express or am I doing something wrong?

**Versions used**

```
$ node -v
v4.2.2

$ npm list express
moneyhouse@1.1.1-dev.2 /Users/dani/Documents/mh-web
├─┬ browser-sync@2.13.0
│ └─┬ browser-sync-ui@0.6.0
│   └─┬ weinre@2.0.0-pre-I0Z7U9OV
│     └── express@2.5.11 
└── express@4.13.4 

$ npm list jade
moneyhouse@1.1.1-dev.2 /Users/dani/Documents/mh-web
├── jade@1.11.0 
└─┬ jade-glob-include@1.0.1
  └── jade@1.3.1
```

Comment: Try print `req` and `page-result` to console for each request A and B like e.g. `console.log(req.params.id, result[0], result[1], req.app.render('company-overview', results))`. If printed data is correct then problem in browser cache else you can see where problem begin.

Comment: This is almost always caused by a variable that you forgot to declare, making it a global variable (which would get overwritten by each request). This isn't a bug in Express.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same error. Eventually it looked like it was being caused by how I was setting res.local in the first place.
I had a simple = operator

```
res.local.VALUE = req.VALUE.
```

'=' does not assign a variable like you would expect, instead it only makes a reference to req.VALUE, meaning as the concurrent request comes in and req.VALUE updates, the value could get swapped.

I solved this by cloning the object:

```
res.local.VALUE = _.clone(req.VALUE) //using underscore
```

so res.local.VALUE was no longer tied to req but was it's own object.

Comment: For each request, both `req` and `res` are _completely new_ objects, they don't get reused for other requests so they can't interfere with each other. You probably solved the symptom but not the underlying problem.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. To be fair, my solution also involved eliminating some unnecessary variables which could have been badly declared